# C++ How to Get three separate date values (day, month, year) from one integer value

Tags: c++, date

Alright, I ask the user for date in (yyyy/mm/dd) format, then it goes down to a function in this case dateSplit. I understand how I can the year since I know its always gonna be the first four digits I can modulus it. Anyone know of a way to do the month and the day here is the code I have so far:

```
void dateSplit(int date, int& year, int& day, int& mon)
{
    // date % 10000 is a floating point value but i put it into an int to cut the back off
    date % 10000 = year;

}
```

Does anyone understand how i can just read the middle two numbers and the last two?

Figured I would put my main code here so people can see the whole picture:

```
int main()
{
    // Variable Declarations
    string airportCode, lat, longitude, timeZone;
    int date;
    char contin = 'Y';
    while (contin == 'Y' || contin == 'y')
    {
        // Ask User for Airport Code
        cout << "Please Enter an Airport Code: ";
        cin >> airportCode;

        //Call to retrieve information
        retrieveFromFile(airportCode, lat, longitude, timeZone);

        //Call for date
        cout << endl << "Please Enter a date(yyyy/mm/dd): ";
        cin >> date;

        // Continue running program?
        cout << endl << "Would you like to continue? (Y/N): ";
        cin >> contin;

    }
}
```

This is the code that finally did it:

```
     void dateSplit(int date, int& year, int& day, int& mon)
    {
        // Ex. if date is 20150623, then it takes that number
        // moves the decimal place over four digits
        // then cuts off after the decimal point
        // leaving just the first four digits
        year = date / 10000;
        date %= 10000;
        mon = date / 100;
        day = date % 100;




        cout << endl << "Year: " << year
             << endl << "Day : " << day
             << endl << "Month:" << mon;

    }
```

Comment: where is that `date` coming from?

Comment: yyyy/mm/dd is not an int. What do you actually have from the user?

Comment: From the user, I will edit my post and include my main function

Comment: from the user i have, i.e. they enter 2014/06/23, i recieve the number 20140623.

Comment: `2014/06/23` -> `20140623`: `day = date % 100; month = (date / 100) % 100; year = (date / 10000);`

Comment: That is poor: Asking a user to encode a date, but not knowing how to decode.

Comment: make sure you deal with the case of the user entering 2012/6/25

Comment: @user2311215: If the user is entering `2014/06/23` then you should receive `2014/06/23` as a string.  If there is some crazy process in the middle pointlessly converting it into an integer, tell it to STOP, and pass the date on to you as a string.

Comment: Note that if a user enters `2014/06/23` to the `cin >> date;` when `date` is an `int`, then the variable `date` will be `2014`, and the rest will still be in `cin` waiting to be read.  This is a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What you really meant to ask was "How do I read in a date from the user?"

Comment: @BeyelerStudios that works for all except month month has the year and the month stored in to it. But also why does it work I understand the year but not sure how the month is _supposed_ to work

Comment: @MooingDuck The date is supposed to look like this 20130623. I will validate and make sure its 8 characters long before I go and split it up. After it is split up I will validate that each value is possible (such as February 30th or 20154040 wont work)

Comment: @user2311215: If the date is supposed to look like that, then why did you tell the user to enter `yyyy/mm/dd`?  You pretty much guarantee that the user is going to enter the wrong things!

Comment: should i change it to YYYYMMDD?

Comment: you should take in yyyy/mm/dd and split the string into 3 parts using the / as delimiter (string.split). YOu now have the 3 pieces you want

Comment: I will ask. Its for my class and we have to split it up and then use his functions for date validation and counting the days in the month and so on. So i asked him if i am allowed to edit his functions to fit my needs

Comment: @user2311215: The normal thing to do would be `cin >> year >> seperator >> month >> seperator >> day;` and then no splitting is ever needed.

Comment: thats so simple but it cant work my case. The instructions say all one integer.

Comment: @user2311215 my code produces the same output as Evans' i.e. `month` := `(20140623/100) % 100 == 201406 % 100 == 6`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use division and modulos to chop it up, something like:

```
year = date % 10000;
date /= 10000;
month = date % 100;
day = date / 100;
```

Comment: I edited your code as seen in my latest edit. But marking you as answerer because you answered it.